# How can I create redundant EC2 instances when also using EBS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, failover, amazon-ebs

I am searching for a host for a web application that must interact with a few terabytes worth of files. One solution I'm considering is to host the application on Amazon EC2 with multiple EBS instances attached to it. This looks like it would solve my problem, but since EBS can be attached to only one EC2 instance, I'm not sure how I can add redundancy of the application in case of failure. I would like multiple EC2 instances in multiple zones with a load balancer, but this doesn't seem doable, since I can't have two EC2 instances talk to the same EBS instance.

How can I create a resilient application when using EC2 with EBS?

Comment: Must you have block-level access to the data? If not, S3 is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to skin this cat, but perhaps the most simple is to have a main "storage" node that has a high amount of network and storage IO bandwidth, which then exports its filesystem out to your application nodes via NFS. Then all of the application nodes will have the same "view" of the storage.

To increase resiliency of the storage node, you can look into technologies like drbd (to keep the storage volume synchronized to a hot standby server), or possibly even a cluster filesystem like Ceph or GlusterFS.

Needless to say, since you're using NFS, this should only be done within a VPC. But then again, all EC2 customers should be using VPC anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We're looking at putting ArcGIS on Amazon which doesn't yet work with S3 (they are working on adding support), so EBS it is. This looks like a good solution to our concerns around resiliency. Thanks again.